# globbing behaviour is being replaced by the print of a token

Tags: bash, glob

This is a test of [globbing](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html). Note that globbing works as expected for $PATH and $NOTHER... but not for $JAVACLASSPATH. Instead the token is echoed even though there is no match because there are no file names that contain a colon `:`.

```
> ls -l
total 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 brian brian   6 Sep  7 16:20 lib.txt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 brian brian 102 Sep  7 16:18 test.sh
> cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
PATH='*'
JAVACLASSPATH='lib:*'
NOTHER='lib*'
echo $PATH
echo $JAVACLASSPATH
echo $NOTHER

> ./test.sh
lib.txt test.sh
lib:*
lib.txt
>
```

Why is the token echoed? It seems that globbing is disabled which is surprising (but convenient for Java programmers because a glob expansion uses space delimiters which is wrong on Linux where java needs `:` delimiters between classes and it's also convenient because * has a special meaning for java because it means "all the JAR files").

**Edit: As heemayl has shown, when there is no match glob produces an unchanged token and it is documented behaviour. This means a Java classpath will see the * which means "all the JAR files" which could be a nice side-effect but surprising side-effects are bad.**

Comment: Don't use `PATH` for your own data; it already has a use. (Try running `ls` after setting `PATH='*'`.) In general, don't use *any* variable names that consist solely of uppercase letters.

Comment: Thanks. You're right PATH should not be used. No harm was done because it was inside a script that will be discarded after it served its purpose for this question.

Comment: Even inside the script, you may not be able to run any external commands if they cannot be found via `PATH` lookup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are matching files in the current directory with the glob patterns and there is no file that starts with `lib:` in the current directory. If you had a file like `lib:txt` then the glob pattern `lib:*` would expand to that instead.

Also when any file is not matched by the glob pattern, the pattern is treated literally, quoting relevant portion of `man bash`:

> If no matching filenames are found, and the shell option nullglob is not enabled, the word is left unchanged.

if you want you can prevent this behavior by using `nullglob` shell option:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

Comment: "the pattern is treated literally"? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: > ls lib:*                                                                                                           
ls: cannot access lib:*: No such file or directory

Comment: Hmmm... no match means return it unchanged. Smells a little fishy?

Comment: @H2ONaCl Why is that?

Comment: Because to determine no match you have to determine two strings are equal, that is, unchanged, but they could be equal by coincidence. Better to return an empty list if you are using C# or Java. Linux has a lot of C code and it's older than the "good" languages.

Comment: @H2ONaCl If that's the behavior you want, then set the nullglob  option. But beware that you'll get unexpected results in many situations, for example `ls /etc/*.nonexistentextension` will "expand" to just `ls`, which will then list all files in the current directory.

Comment: I want globbing. I just don't like the fact that it returns the unchanged string and I was speculating about why that choice was made.